# Expression Engine: Synchronising development and live environments

Tags: php, mysql, workflow, expressionengine

I have read some post about this already but they seem quite old (2008) and I am hoping someone might have a more elegant solution.

I would like to know how Expression Engine developers are working with a local test and live environment workflow.

I have Expression Engine 2.8.1 running on my live environment (Debian web server). I would like to develop my channels, channel fields, themes and other content configurations in a local test environment on my laptop (MAMP server, VirtualBox VM, whatever). Once I am happy I would like to push my changes to the live server.

The tricky part is that the specific changes exist both in the database and the file system. Further more I don’t just want to push my whole database to the live server as the paths / urls and other configuration options will be different for each.

I am using the file based templates which makes that part of the process easier but the database configurations are still a problem. Is there a simple clean way to export / import a the content configuration tables between these environments?

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most people are using a variety of plugins to get synchronisation, including Low Variables for Global Variables as files and Snippet Sync to do the same for snippets.

As for syncing database changes there is currently no synchronisation option to sync Channel Entries etc. You could write a plugin to execute SQL from a directory but then you would have to code all your changes in SQL..

If you have the ability to have the Prod and Staging (Test) server communicate with each other then you could setup database level replication across the two but I would advise against this as it would mean that any changes in Prod/staging will be replicated over to the other server.

Yu can however setup multiple environments for expression engine with a bit of slight code modification. For example I use various configs for different environments, my file system structure is similar to this:

- System
- Themes
- Images
- Config
- - config.env.php
- - config.local.php
- - config.prod.php
- - config.staging.php
- - config.master.php

In the config.env.php:

```
<?php
/*
Environment Declaration
*/
if ( ! defined('ENV'))
{
    switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) 
    {
        // === PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENTS
        case 'host_name' :
            define('ENV', 'prod');
            define('ENV_FULL', 'Production');
            define('ENV_DEBUG', FALSE);
            define('ENV_TYPE', 'production');
        break;
        // === STAGING ENVIRONMENTS
        case 'host_name' :
            define('ENV', 'stage');
            define('ENV_FULL', 'Staging');
            define('ENV_DEBUG', FALSE);
            define('ENV_TYPE', 'staging');
        break;
        // === DEFAULT TO LOCAL
        default :
            define('ENV', 'local'); 
            define('ENV_FULL', 'Local'); 
            define('ENV_DEBUG', FALSE); 
            define('ENV_TYPE', 'local'); 
        break;
    }
}
/* End of file config.env.php */
/* Location: ./config/config.env.php */
```

Then in each of the config.{environment}.php files you can do things similar to this:
config.prod.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Production config overrides & db credentials
 * 
 * Our database credentials and any environment-specific overrides
 * 
 */

// safeguard for now
error_reporting(E_ALL);
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$env_db['hostname'] = 'dbhost';
$env_db['username'] = 'dbuser';
$env_db['password'] = 'dbpassword';
$env_db['database'] = 'dbname';


/* End of file config.prod.php */
/* Location: ./config/config.prod.php */
```

you could also put config overrides in your environment configs as well. I have added a sample config.master.php to pastebin, here: http://pastebin.com/t9L2Ef1E

No the last thing to do is add a bit of code to the /system/expressionengine/config/config.php and database.php files.

fistly the /system/expressionengine/config/config.php file, you need to add the following code (be warned that your file paths may be different so you may need to update the following code to suit your needs)

Add this to the bottom of the file:

```
require(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../config/config.master.php'));
```

Then in /system/expressionengine/config/database.php remove all your db settings (so you have a vanilla file) and add in the config path, like so:

> $active_group = 'expressionengine'; $active_record = TRUE;
>
> $db['expressionengine']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
>   $db['expressionengine']['dbprefix'] = 'exp_';
>   $db['expressionengine']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
>   $db['expressionengine']['swap_pre'] = 'exp_';
>   $db['expressionengine']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
>   $db['expressionengine']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
>   $db['expressionengine']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
>   $db['expressionengine']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
>   $db['expressionengine']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
>
> require(realpath(dirname(**FILE**) .
>   '/../../../config/config.master.php'));
>
> /* End of file database.php */ /* Location:
>   ./system/expressionengine/config/database.php */

that should allow you to use the same file base and still be able to deploy to dev, staging and production with no issues via source control.

I have in fact just set this up with a few of my clients and its working flawlessly. Just an FYI you may need to pay for some EE modules to help facilitate the saving as files for variables and snippets.